# Controller action is called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I've noticed, that "index" action of my controller is called twice.

The action has following structure:

```
def index

  if params[:tags].nil?
     # [fork #1] just return the whole collection of model
     @items = Item.all
  else
     # [fork #2] filter items by tags
     @items = Item.select_by_tags params[:tags]
  end

  # Another operations with @items
  # The result will be incorrect, because, when tags in params are specified,
  # controller action will be first executed for fork #2, and then for fork #1.
  # In view, i get @items from fork #2 and result of THIS piece of code for fork #1
end
```

On the page i have links with URLs, like "/items?tags=tag1, tag2", clicking on them i get "index" action, called twice

I have no idea, why this happens ...

Comment: What is the evidence that you have that this is being called twice?

Answer (score 5):

I've figured it out.

The reason of such a behavior was a JavaScript code, being called after page load. This code implements deep-linking for some parts of the page.

Be careful about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am noticing the same behaviour, my controller action saves some data to the database and the javascript code on my view is calling this action twice resulting in 2 records being created in the database. When I comment out the <script> tag in the view this doesnt happen so I know its the javascript in the view re-calling the controller action. How did you resolve this? What help / docs did you find to help. Im so glad I came across your question! :-) cheers

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and in our case it was an offending pjax code with 6s of timeout resulting in one extra request (i.e. one extra regular HTML request) if pjax didn't complete in 6s.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is whether you have PostCSS listed as a dependency in your `package.json`. If you do, and you *don't* have a `postcss.config.json` file, **fix that**. The most basic file appears to be

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: []
}
```

Restart your server, reload your page, and check the server log. There should be only *one* request being reported as processed.

Very late to the party, but hope this helps someone. I was temporarily stumped in a trivial Rails 6.1.4.1 app seeing the log.